# java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Glide.with(getContext()).load(profileImage).into(profileView);

**The above line is get error to the app to crash. I have added this in a fragment on create method as follows.**

```
private CircleImageView profileView;
private TextView fullNameTextPP, mobileNoTextPP;
private ImageView addProfile;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    fullNameTextPP = view.findViewById(R.id.full_name_nav_header);
    mobileNoTextPP = view.findViewById(R.id.mobileNo_nav_header);
    profileView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_images_nav_header);
    addProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.addProfile__nav_header);

    
    if (currentUser == null) {
        fullNameTextPP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mobileNoTextPP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        profileView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid())
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String fullNAme = task.getResult().getString("fullName");
                    String mobile = task.getResult().getString("phoneNumber");
                    String profileImage = task.getResult().getString("profile");

                    fullNameTextPP.setText(fullNAme);
                    mobileNoTextPP.setText(mobile);

                    if (profileImage.equals("")) {
                        addProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        addProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        **Glide.with(getContext()).load(profileImage).into(profileView);**
                    }
                } else {
                    String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}
```

And I am using bootto menu bar,my Account Fragment XML

```
enter code here<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/account_vertical_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and one more include XML layout is

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_images_nav_header"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_changed"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/full_name_nav_header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arimo_bold"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Welcome Reader"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#4C4B4B"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/goToProfile"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.204"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_images_nav_header"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mobileNo_nav_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="+91 XXXXXXXX23"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#807D7D"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/full_name_nav_header"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/full_name_nav_header" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/goToProfile"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:onClick="goToProfile"
    android:tint="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addProfile__nav_header"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_background_white"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_images_nav_header"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profile_images_nav_header"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_images_nav_header"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_outline_camera_alt_24"
    app:tint="#D6D2D2" />
```

**You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).**

Thanks for advance.
HELP

Comment: Can you add activity where you attached fragment?

Comment: yes I attached to bottom nneu bar.

Comment: Have you tried to change `getContext()` into `getApplicationContext()`? Does it  work this way?

Comment: This issue resolved by if (getActivity ! =null) {
....
}
Thanks for support.